# ajax crossdomain post via node.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, .htaccess, cross-domain, cors

I set up an ajax post to a php file, which uses htaccess CORS to answers with a simple html string.  The twist is, the ajax post will work when i use a xmapp server instead of my node.js server. Also i tested it with 2 different target domains, both with the same htaccess an the same php file. With sending from xampp both work, with sending from node.js only one works.

**Error:**
XMLHttpRequest: Only GET method is supported

Javascript ran in node.js:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: Customer[i]['phplink'],
            crossDomain: true,
            async: true,
            data: {
                status: 'hello',
                cachingtrap: (Math.random())
                },
            timeout: 4000,
            dataType : 'html',
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('online:'+Customer[i]['name']);
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown+ +textStatus+" "+responseData);

            }
        });
```

htaccess:

```
# with AJAX withCredentials=false (cookies NOT sent)
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"                   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE" 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
RewriteEngine On                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]
# with AJAX withCredentials=true (cookies sent, SSL allowed...)
SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN (.*) ORIGIN=$1
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE" 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN}e"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]
```

Target php file:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
    echo round(microtime(true) * 1000);
} else {
    echo "Hello World";
}
?>
```

Comment: What does NodeJS have to do with this issue?

Comment: I send this ajax from an node.js server, when i send it from an apache server, it works

Comment: It's not "cross-domain" from Node. I'm not sure why you're using jQuery either ...

Comment: It's crossdomain. Customer[i]['phplink'] is a link to a complete different domain. I made it more clear in the error report

Comment: Cross-domain is a browser issue, not a server issue. Node.JS shouldn't have any issues with "Cross-domain" traffic.

Comment: okay, can you Plesse explain to me what are other possibilities for my error?

Comment: Try removing the destination server htaccess file temporarily.

Comment: Thank you, i will test it in approximatly  4 hours.

Comment: Tested it, same error message as before :(

Comment: I don't understand where you've got the XMLHttpRequest object from? It's not part of Node.JS. Why not just use: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: That's a good question. I simply didn't know about http request. I wrote my Programm for execution in Browser first, so i just Copy pasted it into my node.JS Server and imported jquery. i will try your answer after todays lectures. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use given code for nodejs express ([more example click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors#)) :

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'example.com');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
}
```